# Can I change the Applications Dropdown shortcut to Super not Alt+F2?

Tags: applications, keyboard-shortcuts

I am used to using Super on Ubuntu to open the search. Can I set <kbd>Super</kbd> to be the shortcut instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?

Or does elementary OS not support Modifier key only bindings? I know that OS X doesn't because I wanted <kbd>Super</kbd> for the Spotlight search, and couldn't have it.

Comment: I too would prefer to just use the `Super` key, but I remember reading somewhere that it was not possible. Let's see what people with more knowledge say about this.

Comment: I believe there's an issue where the <kbd>Super</kbd> key is trapped somehow, and undetectable. I believe it's an upstream Gnome thing.

Comment: Although not as convenient as only <Super>, <Super> + <SpaceBar> does the same as Alt + F2

Comment: Do you want to change the super key to open slingshot, is that what you're asking?

Comment: there is also Super-Space. Clicking it a second time closes Applications, a feature that is not present in Alt-F2 and is not present in the solution that replaces that.

Comment: why you might nor want to change the default Super-Space: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/366/170

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open the Terminal by holding <kbd>Super</kbd> and pressing <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run this command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['Super_L', 'Super_R']"`

3. Either revel in the glory of your newfound shortcut, or change back by running:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['<Super>space', '<Alt>F2']"`

Comment: there is a little problem though: the new Super key lacks a feature that is present in Super-Space. Indeed, your solution replaces ALT-F2, not Super-Space, which **pressed a second time also closes** Applications

Comment: Much better improvement of my answer. Good work

Comment: Do note that **this will mess with all other shortcuts that use Super** and is the reason it's not the default. i.e. Super left/right to switch workspaces gets weird because now the app launcher is opening, super+drag to move windows around gets messed up, etc.

Comment: hi, I am not sure what command I used to change to <Super>space to <Super> as I did that a long time ago, I tried the second command but it did not change. Now all three combinations open app launcher.

Answer (score 6):

You can set slingshot to launch by only pressing the super key by typing the following command into your terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['Super_L']"
```

Comment: Was looking for that entry to complete my answer since I had it configured that way in my system. Also useful to change Super + Up to toggle-maximized

Comment: I just have a list of things I do to configure my eOS installs. Luckily, that was on that list. :)

Comment: This is the answer, thank you very much @Crutchcorn!

Comment: Anytime! Glad I could help

Comment: @Crutchcorn While this answers the question, it is good practice to include steps to revert the setting. Right now users would not know how to change it back (without discovering the graphical methods).

Comment: It should also be noted that pressing `Super` again in this context does _not_ close the applications menu.

Comment: Can I set it to Super_L *or* Super_R?

Comment: @Tim The default setting is `['<Super>space', '<Alt>F2']`, so I would assume `['Super_L', 'Super_R']` would work for both.