# Why is there a difference between Super-Space and other shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, slingshot

By default the application launcher is called with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. ([It can be changed](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/27/170).)

But there is a difference; after showing the Applications launcher, the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut also hides it if pressed again; <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't do that.

And neither do other shortcuts:

The same difference is present if the default shortcuts are changed as indicated in the answers to the linked question: the launcher is shown but not hidden with just the Super key (unlike in Ubuntu Unity). That is my main reason against giving up the default <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut in favor of just  <kbd>Super</kbd>  on elementary OS.

---

What is special behind <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is hardcoded right in to Slingshot. It does not check system settings for different keybindings.

---

I grabbed the latest source code and had a look for the word "Super". I came across this in one of the source files:

```
// Handle super+space when the user is typing in the search entry 
private bool search_entry_key_press (Gdk.EventKey event) { 
    if ((event.keyval == Gdk.Key.space) && ((event.state & Gdk.ModifierType.SUPER_MASK) != 0)) { 
        hide (); 
        return true; 
    }   

    switch (event.keyval) { 
        case Gdk.Key.Tab: 
            // context view is disabled until we get plugins that are actually 
            // useful with a context 
            // search_view.toggle_context (!search_view.in_context_view); 
            return true; 
    }   

    return false; 
}
```

You can see that it is hardcoded to only check for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in order to hide.

The source code can be found at [Revision 558, Line 413](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/slingshot/trunk/view/558/src/SlingshotView.vala#L413).

Comment: Brilliant ;) A+ for the effort!

Comment: @TW80000 Would you be able to give a filename & number? We should be able to link to the source code and this is done.

Comment: Here you go! http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/slingshot/trunk/view/head:/src/SlingshotView.vala#L413

Comment: Thanks! That link doesn't specify a revision, but I can't find a way to do that, and it can always be done later. Unfortunately, StackExchange won't let me award a bounty for the first 24 hours, so I'll have to come back tomorrow.

Comment: I found a way and updated the link to contain the revision number. Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: So basically it's a bug because it does not check for the actual shortcut.

Comment: I would say it's not so much of a bug as a feature they didn't choose to include. But yeah, basically!