# Super Key Menu Unhide

Tags: slingshot, menu

I used the command below to enable the Super Key Menu.

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['Super_L', 'Super_R']"`

Command Source: [Can I change the Applications Dropdown shortcut to Super not Alt+F2?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/27/can-i-change-the-applications-dropdown-shortcut-to-super-not-altf2)

I want to know, if I can use the Super Key to hide the Menu after calling it. Currently, I need to use Esc.

Comment: This is explicitly not supported because the super key is used as a system-wide modifier. For instance, you can use super and an arrow key to navigate workspaces or enter the multi-tasking view. See [this comment](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/27/can-i-change-the-applications-dropdown-shortcut-to-super-not-altf2?lq=1#comment1001_98).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known bug with slingshot in that its close modifier is hardcoded. You can find more information and +1 here https://bugs.launchpad.net/slingshot/+bug/1507524

Comment: Ok, thank you. I didn't find that before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to open and hide the menu too.

Comment: Here's why: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/366/170

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible as for now. The developers are also clear about not being interested on supporting custom key bindings.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely true, if we didn't want to allow custom shortcuts, we'd hardcode them, not give you a nice settings pane to change them all.

Comment: @LewisGoddard - Super-Space is hardcoded: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/486/170

Comment: I am aware, I awarded that answer a bounty, but that single shortcut is only hard-coded for technical reasons. There is a bug filed somewhere about changing that.