# What's the hotkey to run a command?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, command-line

In some distros there is a hotkey that opens a dialog box to run a terminal command.

Does this exist in elementary OS, and if so what's the hotkey? If not, how can I add a custom hotkey?

Comment: I have added an answer (and remember to mark it as answer if it works)

Comment: I have added another answer (and remember to mark it as answer if it works)

Answer (score 3):

Slingshot is also **that**: a dialog box to run a command.

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> , type the command and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Another shortcut is <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

Comment: no, open de aplication menu, slingshot I think is the name.

Comment: @koxmoz Do you want to not open the application menu

Comment: @SuiciDoga - isn't Super-Space the default to launch slingshot? why alt-f2? is there a difference (I mean beside [this one](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/486/170))?

Comment: @koxmoz - Slingshot is exactly what you ask for: *a dialog box to run a command*. That is triggered by Super-Space (default; [can be changed](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/27/170)). If you want a *terminal* command (as you said, but by mistake I guess), use  Super-T for the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Like in elementary don't exists that option. so I create the file:

```
~/bin/run
```

This is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
## Zenity
command=`zenity --title "Run commands" --entry --text "Command"`
## Bash
eval $command
exit
```

save and change the permission

```
chmod +x ~/bin/run
```

then set a custom shortcut in Preference > keyboard > Shortcut > Custom

```
| command | keys      |
| run     | Super + R |
```

that's it! enjoy .

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal. Then type the command and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to run it

Comment: question edited for more info..

Comment: @koxmoz I gave you the shortcut key

Comment: thats not what I'm looking for, If I run a command that open a daemon like dropbox, when I close the terminal, close the daemon.

Comment: @koxmoz Then just add ` & disown` to the end of the command and then close the terminal.Mark this as answer if it works

Comment: so, there is no dialog box for that in Elementary.

Comment: @koxmoz Yes there is no dialog. You can ask them to add one if you like