# How to enable Alt-F2 command execution with tab-completion?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, launcher

Although the Applications Launcher is [apparently supposed to](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/794454/comments/12) take on the role of `Alt-F2`-like command execution as well, it does not have useful features such as tab-completion of the command, command history, etc.

Is there a way to enable `Alt-F2` functionality in elementaryOS (Loki in this case)?

(The `zenith`-based method [mentioned in this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/whats-the-hotkey-to-run-a-command/5530#5530) doesn't provide these features either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the other comments in [that bug report thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/794454), there are a few other options using external software, to enable full `Alt-F2` functionality.

There's `gmrun` and `synapse`, both of which are available in the apt repository sources to install (`sudo apt install gmrun`, or `sudo apt install synapse`).

`xfrun4` is also mentioned as part of `xfce4-utils` package, but that one doesn't seem to be available in the default repo sources.

`gmrun` is a very small download (<100kB) that produces a simple text box with tab-completion and history, no bells and whistles beyond that.

`synapse` tries to be more comprehensive, perhaps similar to 'Launchy' for Windows or 'Spotlight' on MacOS. It has a pretty good-looking GUI, has those core features of tab-completion and history, along with the ability to search your Images, Audio, Documents, etc. optionally. That predictably brings in allegations of being "bloated" as mentioned in the thread, though that's obviously subjective and depends on your preferences.

To enable the shortcut key:

- for `gmrun`: go to `System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab`, choose `Custom` in the left panel, click on the `+` button at the bottom and enter the name of the program (`gmrun`). Then click on the text that says `Disabled` next to the command name, and press `Alt-F2` to assign that shortcut to it.
- for `synapse`: go to `System settings -> Applications -> Startup`, click on the `+` button at the bottom and enter the name of the program (`synapse`), choose the Synapse program entry shown there. Then, if you wish to have the shortcut to be `Alt-F2` instead of the default `Ctrl-Space` (which didn't reliably work for me, for some reason), start `synapse` manually from the terminal or Launcher, click the small circle on the top right and choose Preferences, and there change the shortcut for Activate to `Alt-F2`. (If the Preferences window doesn't show the actual shortcuts, right click on the window's titlebar and choose Maximize.)