# Keyboard Shortcut for application chooser

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

How can I change the keyboard shortcut for launching the applications menu? I have an extended Mac keyboard and currently have to Hold Ctrl+Alt+Space. I'd like it to be Alt+Space

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing key binding the easy way ?

System settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Applications --> App Launcher

Log out and back in may be required to take effect.

Comment: Yes, I can change it but not to Alt + Space

Comment: Since 'Home' + 'Space' is the default key binding to App launcher and is even hardcoded - [Check this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/366/why-is-there-a-difference-between-super-space-and-other-shortcuts), maybe you need to make sure of the equivalent of 'Home' on your keyboard, or change the key binding with 'gsettings set' [As shown Here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/27/can-i-change-the-applications-dropdown-shortcut-to-super-not-altf2?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> will open the App Launcher on modern versions of elementary OS.