# How can i change keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I want to change my keyboard shortcut for the multitasking view. I want instead of the key combination 'windows' + 'arrow down' only the'windows-key'. Is it possible to do this? And how can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Cassidy James](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/308/cassidy-james) said [over here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/27/can-i-change-the-applications-dropdown-shortcut-to-super-not-altf2?rq=1#comment1001_98):

> Do note that **this will mess with all other shortcuts that use Super** and is the reason it's not the default. i.e. Super left/right to switch workspaces gets weird because now the app launcher is opening, super+drag to move windows around gets messed up, etc

That said, you can open `System Settings`, open `Keyboard`, and then you should be in the `Shortcuts` tab already. Click on what you want to change and set it to whatever you want, although it may require at least two keys this way.

[image: keyboards plug]