# How to set shortcut for brightness

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, brightness

I've an ASUS N56JN and brightness shortcut doesn't work. Usually with my laptop I can do it with FN+F5/F6. How can I solve this issue? Is there a way to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the instructions on [this page](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/how-can-i-change-keyboard-shortcuts?rq=1), but instead go to `Custom` and select the `+` button to add a new keyboard shortcut.  In the custom command, put `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown` or `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp`.  Then click where it says `Disabled` and key in your key combination.

Comment: I've been doing this with xbacklight. Your solution seems better because it uses the indicator.  However it's working in terminal but not as a shortcut, any ideas?

Comment: Found an answer by myself. It needs to be: xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessUp

Comment: make sure to install the hardware level brightness adjustment tool first by issuing sudo apt install xdotool

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting a key binding to the two commands below.

To increase the brightness by 10% use

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```

and to decrease by 10% use

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```