# CTRL + SPACE not working on 0.4 Loki

Tags: release-freya, release-loki

I just installed 0.4 Loki and I notice that CTRL + SPACE doesn't bring up the Applications menu like it did in 0.3.2 Freya. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: In Freya too Applications menu was triggered by Super-Space. That [can be changed](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/98/170) though.

Comment: Interesting. Typing `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu` gives `['<Primary>space']` in Freya, but `['<Super>space','<Alt>F2'']` in Loki. What's the difference between `Primary` and `Super`?

Answer (score 4):

It uses the "super" key + space.

super = windows button.

It's basically an effort to work more like Mac OS